# How to migrate Google Smart Home Actions project and not delete Firebase instance

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I have a Google Actions project which was built using the Smart Home Actions template.  I would like to migrate this project in order to have the same functionality exposed in setting up a Custom project, namely the Actions Builder interface.  Is it possible to upgrade the project or do I need to rebuild the project from scratch using a Custom starter template.

My existing project is currently linked to a Firebase/Firestore instance.  If I have to start over by deleting my project, I do not want the delete project option in the Actions on Google console to delete the Firebase project, which I have confirmed it does.  Any idea on how to prevent this from happening as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Actions project is already configured as a Smart Home project, it cannot be converted into a conversational project. You would need to create a new project.

You don't have to delete your Firebase content, and you can keep your existing Actions project. But your new conversational project will need to follow [Firebase guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides) to connect with a separate project.